# how can i access ImageButton of my_row.xml file in Inventory activity android java

Tags: java, android

hi everyone i am new to android and i am trying to implement image button of my_row.xml file to inventory.java, i dont know how to acccess button of another layout file to mainactivity so pls help to get through this. thank you

this is my Inventory.java file

```
package com.khalidkhira.rentit;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.khalidkhira.rentit.Adapter.CustomAdapter;
import com.khalidkhira.rentit.Database.DBHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Inventory extends AppCompatActivity {
    DBHelper DB;
    RecyclerView recyclerview;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
CardView dataCard;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory);

    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_row, null);
    ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) 
inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.deletes_button);


    recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    DB = new DBHelper(Inventory.this);
    ArrayList<Items> items = DB.getItems();
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(Inventory.this, items);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Inventory.this));
    dataCard = findViewById(R.id.itemCard);


    FloatingActionButton addItem = findViewById(R.id.FABAdd);
    addItem.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Inventory.this, InsertItems.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(view21 -> Toast.makeText(this, "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
}
```

}

and this is my_row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/myRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="65dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/itemCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/teal_light"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name_txt"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/item_name"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            android:foreground="@color/black"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_items_txt"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/total_items"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider2"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            android:foreground="@color/black"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/available_items_txt"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/available_items"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider3"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            android:foreground="@color/black"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_price_txt"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:text="@string/item_price"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider4"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            android:foreground="@color/black"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deletes_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/teal_light"
            android:foreground="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/delete" />
    </TableRow>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

so i want to access this imagebutton in my inventory class but i am unable to do that.
i am stuck at that so pls help me.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do with `view inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_row, null)`

Answer (score 0):

From the `Activity` you can find the views that you inflated with

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory)
```

Where's the button you want to access? If it is a layout you use in a ViewHolder of a RecyclerView then it's from there that you can access it.

Comment: in recyclerView

Comment: So you need to access it from the Adapter that knows the views in each item of the list. Can you post the `CustomAdapter`? And whatever you are using as ViewHolder